# Prove that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)}\,\mathrm dz→0$ if $r \rightarrow 0$, where $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r<R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the function $f(z)$ is continuous on $0<|z-z_0|<R$  and $M(r)$ is the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $0<|z-z_0|=r<R$.  Suppose that $rM(r)  \rightarrow 0$.

Prove that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)} \,\mathrm{d}z \rightarrow 0$ if $r  \rightarrow 0$. Here $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r<R$.

I tried to use the Cauchy inequality $\left|\dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right|  \le \dfrac{Me^r}{r^k}$. But it does not help.

Could someone give a hint, please.

Comment: how could you use Cauchy? you only know $f$ is continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
\big|\int_{C_r}f(z)dz\big|  \leq \int_{C_r}|f(z)||dz| 
$$

Can you find a bound for this integral in terms of a bound for $|f|$ and a property of $C_r$? Does this bound get small when $r \to 0$?

Final step:

> Conclude that $\int_{C_r}|f(z)||dz| \leq L(C_r)\max_{C_r}|f| = 2\pi rM(r) \to 0$

Comment: @Guido A.:I know this inequality. I don't know how to apply  $rM(r)  \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Metso I included the final calculation you need. However, I'd encourage you to first write out this inequality, replace the unknowns for things you do have control of, and stare at it for some time.

Comment: If a change the condition: $|z-z_0|>r_0$ , $M(r)$ is max. of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $|z-z_0|=r>r_0$. Then this integral must be $ \rightarrow 0$ if $r  \rightarrow \infty$. How then your solution solve it?

Comment: If you have some control over $M(r)$, such as $M(r)r \to 0$ when $r \to \infty$, you can use the exact same calculation. Otherwise it may not happen. If $f \equiv 1$ for example, that integral will go to infinity.

Comment: Your inequality is wrong. Perhaps if you change it to $|dz|$ on the right ...

Comment: @zhw. I haven't studied any differential geometry yet, so far I've always treated differentials as notation. Care to explain the distinction?

Comment: Suppose $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ and $f(z) = 1/z.$ Do you think $|\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz|\le \int_\gamma |f(z)|\,dz?.$

Comment: No, $\int_\gamma |f(z)|\,dz$ is a contour integral; it equals $0.$

Comment: Not only that, I didn't integrate properly in my last comment. I see it now. Thanks for taking the time to answer.