# Prove that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)}\,\mathrm dz→0$ if $r \rightarrow \infty$, where $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration

Let the function $f(z)$ is continuous on $|z-z_0|>r_0$ and $M(r)$ is the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $|z-z_0|=r>r_0$. Suppose that $rM(r)  \rightarrow 0$.

Prove that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)} \,\mathrm{d}z \rightarrow 0$ if $r  \rightarrow \infty$. Here $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r$.

The link to the  similar exercise:"[Prove that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)}\,\mathrm dz→0$ if $r \rightarrow 0$, where $C_r$ is the circle $|z-z_0|=r<R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829609/)"

But here the conditions are changed: $r  \rightarrow \infty$ and the cirle $|z-z_0|=r>r_0$.

If the circle has the length $L$ then $\big|\int_{C_r}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\big|  \leq M(r)*L = 2\pi*r*M(r)*L$. How to show then that $\int_{C_r} {f(z)}\,\mathrm dz→0$ if $ r  \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The *identical* approach as in the linked-to Q&A works here as well, just replace $r \to 0 $ by $r \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\left|\int_{C_r}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\right|\leqslant2\pi rM(r),$$you have$$0\leqslant\lim_{r\to\infty}\left|\int_{C_r}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\right|\leqslant2\pi\lim_{r\to\infty}rM(r)=0.$$